# Why is the average value of the function using integrals astronomical despite the scale on the graph and the interval

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I used lagrangian interpolation and for some equations the average value of the function is astronomical despite the polynomial and the points it interpolates.

For example

Polynomial A:

$$(X_0, Y_0) = (62,181)\\
(X_1, Y_1) = (40,210)\\
(X_2, Y_2) = (67,185)\\
(X_3, Y_3) = (19, 201)\\
(X_4, Y_4) = (41, 199)
$$

Lagrangian Polynomial:

$$f(x)=-3893/4980690 x^4+5847/39130x^3-353200229/34864830x^2+121372073/430430x-8446030382/3486483$$

The average value of the function within $19\le x\le 67: 5248520$

Polynomial B:

$$(X_0, Y_0) = (1,200)\\
(X_1, Y_1) = (81,250)\\
(X_2, Y_2) = (32,212)\\
(X_3, Y_3) = (77, 248)\\
(X_4, Y_4) = (93, 245)
$$

$$f(x)=-1173601/155489214720 x^4+28814081/22212744960 x^3-1451597501/22212744960 x^2+3639509257/2549003520 x+1482612997/7463960$$

$$dx=32773432105907/145771138800≈224.8$$

Am I doing something wrong in polynomial A. What is mathematically the cause for this? Thanks!

Comment: `The average value of the function within 19<=x<=67: 5248520`: this is not what I [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D-3893%2F4980690+x%5E4%2B5847%2F39130x%5E3-353200229%2F34864830x%5E2%2B121372073%2F430430-8446030382%2F3486483)

Comment: Well, you've never mentioned an integral in your question.

Comment: The plot from Alpha looks like it is always negative over the range of interest.  That cannot be the Lagrange polynomial for the given points, which are all positive.  I don't know where the error is.  There appears to be an $x$ missing from the first polynomial in the linear term.

Comment: @PhysicsGeek, no, it's because you've lost $x$ in $f(x)$. Now the plot looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D-3893%2F4980690+x%5E4%2B5847%2F39130x%5E3-353200229%2F34864830x%5E2%2B121372073%2F430430x-8446030382%2F3486483) and matches on the points.

Comment: I don't see a reason to trust this site. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+-3893%2F4980690+x%5E4%2B5847%2F39130x%5E3-353200229%2F34864830x%5E2%2B121372073%2F430430x-8446030382%2F3486483+from+x%3D19+to+67) is what wolfram says. Moreover, for average you should compute not $\int_{19}^{67} \ldots$, but $\frac {\int_{19}^{67} \ldots} {67 - 19}$, and now you get a [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28-3893%2F4980690+x%5E4%2B5847%2F39130x%5E3-353200229%2F34864830x%5E2%2B121372073%2F430430x-8446030382%2F3486483%29+%2F+%2867+-+19%29+from+x%3D19+to+67)

Comment: Also, you are mistaken by thinking that `5248520` is a large number. It won't lead to any numerical problems unless you need something like the $7$-th digit after decimal point, e.g. depending on your calculator $((5248520 + 10^{-10}) - 5248520) \cdot 10^{10}$ may be something like 0 instead of 1. of course, you may use it to get even bigger numbers. *They* may lead to problems.

Comment: @PhysicsGeek, can you elaborate when it happens? Integral is always positive when the function is positive. Otherwise, you need to look closely. Increasing/decreasing doesn’t matter

Comment: Recent edits to this question entirely changed it and made the accepted answer nonsensical. I have rolled back to the latest sensible version of the question.

Comment: @PhysicsGeek even  if it is too specific there is not reason to edit the post in unusual ways. Leave it alone and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wolfy,

$\dfrac1{67-19}\int_{19}^{67}(-3893/4980690 x^4+5847/39130x^3-353200229/34864830x^2+121372073/430430x-8446030382/3486483)dx
\approx 218.45
$

To get the average value,
you have to divide by
the length of the interval.

Comment: Someone defaced my answer with total garbage. I have rejected their edit.